# shell remove whitespace after a pattern for the line start with a pattern

Tags: shell, sed

Input:

```
<measType p="1">pmCabinetFanSpeed</measType>
<measType p="2">pmCabinetFanSpeedExternal</measType>
<measType p="3">pmCabinetTemperature</measType>
<measType p="4">pmSpmBarometricAirPressure</measType>
<r p="1">           61          </r>
<r p="2">             </r>
<r p="3">, , , , ,</r>
<r p="4">1314    1537</r>
```

Expected output:

```
<measType p="1">pmCabinetFanSpeed</measType>
<measType p="2">pmCabinetFanSpeedExternal</measType>
<measType p="3">pmCabinetTemperature</measType>
<measType p="4">pmSpmBarometricAirPressure</measType>
<r p="1">61</r>
<r p="2"></r>
<r p="3">,,,,,</r>
<r p="4">13141537</r>
```

Basically, remove all the white space after > with the line start with `<r>`

Any idea?

I have tried `sed -E 's/(<r p=[0-9]+>) /\1/g'`, however it won't keep comma.

Comment: I have a better solution.  sed 's/ //2g' input, however there might be space before <r

Comment: I solved the problem by sed 's/^[ ]*//g;/^<r/s/ //2g' input

Comment: You can also use this sed 's/\s//g' <input> | tr -d '\t'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '{match($0,/>.*</);val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);gsub(/ /,"",val);print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)}'  Input_file
```

Adding non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
{
  match($0,/>.*</);
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  gsub(/ /,"",val);
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
}
'   Input_file
```

In case you want to save the output into same Input_file then add following into above code.

`> temp_file  &&  mv Input_file  temp_file` to save the output into Input_file itself.